# AngularJS Error handling based on status code

Tags: angularjs

in my current angularJS, i handled error, whenever an error occures, it through one error msg but i dont need like this:

I want when `400 (Bad Request)` error, it should through a msg like "**Your submitted data already exist, please try with another data"**

and when `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` it should through msg like **" You are not connected with internet"**

here you go for my current snippet:

```
  $scope.formModel = {}; // It will post data and handle both success and error, 
  $scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.successPost = 'You have successfully submitted your Contact';
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.successPost = '';
        },4000);
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
      }, function(response){
        $scope.errorPost = 'Ooops! An Error Ocuured saving your contact, please try again later';
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.errorPost = '';
        },6000);
      });
      $scope.formModel = {};
      $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine(); 
  };
```

Above snippet, through an error for any kind of error but i need custom exactly what error occured, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Status is provided by the `status` property of the `response` object.
The status message is provided as the `statusText` property of the `response` object.

```
  $scope.formModel = {}; // It will post data and handle both success and error, 
  $scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.successPost = 'You have successfully submitted your Contact';
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.successPost = '';
        },4000);
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
      }, function(response){
        $scope.errorPost = 'Ooops! An Error Ocuured saving your contact, please try again later';
        if (response.status == 400) {
            $scope.errorPost = "Your submitted data already exist, please try with another data";
        };
        if (response.status == 500) {
            $scope.errorPost = "You are not connected with internet";
        });
        console.log("Error status",response.status);
        console.log("Error message",response.statusText);
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.errorPost = '';
        },6000);
      });
      $scope.formModel = {};
      $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine(); 
  };
```

From the Docs:

> The `response` object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.
> - **xhrStatus** – `{string}` – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (`complete`, `error`, `timeout` or `abort`).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)

Comment: I notice the doc but i am not getting this yet